# Match all text heights to the largest

Tags: javascript, react-native

What is the best way to make a row of texts match the maximum height of the tallest text within that row? The code looks like this:

```
<View style={styles.field}>
     <Text style={styles.titleCoverage}>Coverage</Text>
     <Text style={styles.titleFaceAmount}>Face Amount</Text>
     <Text style={styles.titlePremiums}>Premiums</Text>
</View>
```

with a stylesheet looking like this:

```
field: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    width: '95%',
    alignItems: 'center',
},
titleCoverage: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9', 
    marginBottom: 5,
    width: 200, 
    paddingTop: 3,
    paddingBottom: 3
},
titleFaceAmount: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9', 
    marginBottom: 5,
    width: 80, 
    paddingTop: 3,
    paddingBottom: 3
},
titlePremiums: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#2980b9', 
    marginBottom: 5,
    width: 80, 
    paddingTop: 3,
    paddingBottom: 3
},
```

In this situation, the "Face Amount" text has a taller height than the other two. Given a variable text value that might be large or small, what is the best way to ensure that all three in the row maintain the same height as the largest one?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have setting the container's display property to flex.

After this you might need to set the container's `align-items` property to `stretch`.

```
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
```

More details are here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

And, for our use case I think that should be an additional entry: `alignItems: 'stretch'` in `styles.field` map.